# ios Parse Facebook Login Permissions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, permissions

Am I requesting my facebook permissions for the Parse LoginViewController correctly using the `[logInViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:permissionsArray, nil]];`

In my root view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   if (![PFUser currentUser] || // Check if user is cached
        ![PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) { // Check if user is linked to Facebook

        NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"public_profile", @"user_birthday", @"user_photos", @"user_about_me", @"user_likes", @"user_relationship_details"];

        LoginViewController *logInViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        [logInViewController setDelegate:self];
        [logInViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:permissionsArray, nil]];
        [logInViewController setFields: PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton];

        // Present Log In View Controller
        [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

    } else {
        [self getUserInfo];


        }
}
```

Because when I call this method it always returns "No", for any permission I try check for?

```
-(void)getUserInfo {

    if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"user_birthday"]) {
        NSLog(@"Yes");

    }else{
        NSLog(@"No");
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just try for @email permission and see if it's working.

Comment: I have tried for the @email permission, how come the requested permissions are not working?

Comment: Did you get the email permission? I take it that your app is in development - do you have a role in the app? Developer or Admin? 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review